# Чтение из файла (Scanner)

Tags: java

Как можно читать текст из файла без пробелов в начале и конце строки с помощью `Scanner` и записывать в массив?

вот мой код:

```
public static void main(String [] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        String rows[] = new Scanner(new File("file.txt")).useDelimiter("\\Z").next().split("\n");
```

Answer (score 2):

Так как заранее не известно количество строк в файле я бы предложил воспользоваться динамическим массивом. В Java одной из имплементаций динамического массива является ArrayList
Как вариант:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ReadFile {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    File file = new File("file.txt");
    List<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();
    Scanner sc;    

    try {

       sc = new Scanner(file);

        while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = sc.nextLine().trim(); 
                    //.trim() осуществляет обрезание пробелов
            strings.add(line)   
            System.out.println(line); //печать строки в стандартный вывод
        }

    } 
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        sc.close();
    }

    String []stringsArray = (String []) strings.toArray();
  }
}
```

В рузельтате в массиве `stringsArray` будут строчки из файла, обрезанные по краям.